# Do any package managers provide select-one dependencies

Tags: packages, dependencies, features, package-managers

With jquery very slowly being phased out you get into more and more situations where library X will run with either jquery or zepto.js (but at least one is required).

No package managers that I can think of however allow you to express dependencies like this. If I was to propose this feature to - say - bower, is there precedent for how it might look?

Comment: Seems like it would be off topic on SO as there isn't really a correct answer and its more of a general question about programming. Why do you think its off topic?

Comment: Better try to ask such questions on http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`dpkg` / APT has supported this for ages.

There are two mechanisms for this. One is alternate dependencies by simply declaring the dependency like this:

```
Depends: jquery | zeptojs
```

You will declare that the package depends on either `jquery` or `zepto.js`.

The other mechanism is *Virtual Packages*. A package can declare that it `Provides` a virtual package and then other packages can depend on that virtual package.

For example, both the `jquery` package and the `zeptojs` package can declare that they provide the `jquery-api` virtual package, and then your app can depend on `jquery-api`. This has the added advantage that if in the future a *third* new JQuery-compatible library appears in the market, only the author of that package has to put a `Provides: jquery-api` line in his package description. You don't have to change your app and it will just work with the new library.

In your app:

```
Depends: jquery-api
```

In JQuery:

```
Provides: jquery-api
```

In Zepto.JS:

```
Provides: jquery-api
```

In the brand-new yet-to-be-written awesome new JQuery replacement:

```
Provides: jquery-api
```

Comment: oh awesome. Thanks, glad to know the terminology for this as well.